# How to load multiple mongodb collections using python in spark

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to read all the collections of one of the db in mongodb. There are a total of 31 collections, but I use mongo's official code to read only one collection at a time. If I want to read all collections,except using the for loop. Is there a faster way to read all the collections of one of the db in mongodb?